# linear algebra about commutativity

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A\in M_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $A\not=\lambda I$. Let $S$ be $\{B\in M_2(\mathbb{C}): AB=BA\}$. Show that $XY=YX$ for any $X,Y \in S$.

What about the higher dimension?

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is not a scalar matrix, then each matrix commuting with $A$
has the form $uI+vA$. It suffices to verify this when $A$ is in Jordan Normal Form.

For larger matrices consider
$$\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}.$$